# Timer in react web app not working in mobile when browser closed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm working on a React based timer app. The countdown works perfectly both in web and mobile but it freezes/miscounts when on the browser in mobile, it is minimized or closed to background. Is there any way of getting the timer to run as expected in the background when browser minimized or phone locked?

```
timer = () => {
if (!this.props.paused) {
  this.setState(
    prevState => ({ time: prevState.time - 1 }),
    () => {
      if (this.state.time === 0) {
        clearInterval(this.state.countdown);
        this.props.onEnd();
      }
    }
  );
}
};
```

This is my code for the timer function which decrements time and calls onEnd function when countdown over.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const countdown = setInterval(this.timer, 1000);
}
```

This is called every 1 second by the setInterval function.

Is there an easy way of getting the timer to work as expected from background for mobiles? I've been recommended service workers. In a create-react-app setup what can be done to implement this functionality using service workers?

Comment: You might want to check this out: https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task

Comment: Isn't that for native apps? I'm talking a pure web implementation, to be run on web.

Comment: You need a native application, or check with dates and not a timer, since you can not control when the browser goes to "sleep" mode. When the browser is send to the background stops processing the javascript because "is not in use"